# jquery text inside each function search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

It prints an empty string, supposed to print "Admin" and hide the elements that don't contains the searchBar text, keyUp is being triggeree, it just gives me an empty string when i console.log($(this).text()), searchBar is an input field to search things in a list

```js
const searchBar = $(".users-layout .search input")
searchBar.on("keyup", () => {
  if (searchBar.val() != "") {
    $(".users-list-name").each(() => {
      if (!$(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(searchBar.val().toLowerCase())) {
        console.log($(this).text())
        $(this).hide()
      } else {
        console.log($(this).text())
        $(this).show()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="users-list">
  <a href="#" class="back-icon"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="details">
      <span class="users-list-name">Admin</span>
      <p>Test Message</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status-dot"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="users-list">
  <a href="#" class="back-icon"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="details">
      <span class="users-list-name">Admin</span>
      <p>Test Message</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status-dot"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this yourself? Are you sure the `keyup` event is even being triggered correctly? What does `searchBar.val()` return? What does `$(this).text().toLowerCase()` return? Please edit your question to make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We have no idea what most of your selectors/variables return without the relevant HTML added to your question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` was refering to the window. I fixed it so it grabs the actual element: `let elem = $(".users-list-name")[index]`

```js
const searchBar = $(".users-layout .search input")
searchBar.on("keyup", () => {
  if (searchBar.val() != "") {
    $(".users-list-name").each(index => {
    let elem = $(".users-list-name")[index]
      if (!$(elem).text().toLowerCase().includes(searchBar.val().toLowerCase())) {
        console.log($(elem).text())
        $(elem).hide()
      } else {
        console.log($(elem).text())
        $(elem).show()
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="users-layout">
  <div class="search">
    <input />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="users-list">
  <a href="#" class="back-icon"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="details">
      <span class="users-list-name">Admin</span>
      <p>Test Message</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status-dot"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="users-list">
  <a href="#" class="back-icon"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="details">
      <span class="users-list-name">Admin</span>
      <p>Test Message</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="status-dot"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

at the end i resolved like this

```
searchBar.on("keyup", ()=>{
  if (searchBar.val() != "") {
    $(".users-list-name").each((i, obj)=>{
      console.log($(obj))
      if (!$(obj).text().toLowerCase().includes(searchBar.val().toLowerCase())){
        $(obj).parent().parent().parent().hide()
      } else {
        $(obj).parent().parent().parent().show()
      }
    }
  )
} else {
  $(".users-list").show()
}
})
```